# RegExp matching certain characters after a word

Tags: regex

I'm having problems with a regular expression. I have a string like this:

```
host=HOME_SERVER value=\"83.169.217.62 - km-meat-170929 [04/May/2018:00:01:13 +0300] \\\"POST /platform/services/2.0/EnterpriseService HTTP/1.1\\\" 200 4075 \\\"-\\\" \\\"1C+Enterprise/8.3\\\" 0.141\" 1526823558639987327
```

I would like to find all backslashes and spaces after "value", so far I've come up with this:

```
value(.+)
```

How to find further backslashes and spaces?

The proposed solution works fine in java:

```
 s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|value=)([^\\\\\\s]*)[\\s\\\\]+", "$1$2")
```

How can I change it to not delete matches, but replace them from, for example, "*"?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I want to delete all "\" and " " after "value".

Comment: This looks like an XY problem: where did you get that string from? This should be fixed at the source...

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: @Matt.G programming language - java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all whitespace and backslashes after the `value=` substring.

So, the pattern to remove is `[\s\\]`, but the trick is to make it only match after a certain value. This is the case where the [`\G` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) can help. You may match the `value=` or the end of the previous match with `(\\G(?!^)|value=)` and then get to the whitespace or backslash using `([^\\\\\\s]*)`. Note the capturing groups, we may later restore these captures using `$1$2` replacement backreferences in the replacement pattern.

You may use

```
s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|value=)([^\\\\\\s]*)[\\s\\\\]+", "$1$2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKm0wB/1)

**Details**

- `(\\G(?!^)|value=)` - Group 1 (its value is referred to with `$1`): end of the previous match (`\\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a `value=` substring
- `([^\\\\\\s]*)` - Group 2 (its value is referred to with `$1`): zero or more chars other than whitespace (`\s`) or `\\` chars
- `[\\s\\\\]+` - one or more whitespace (`\s`) or `\\` chars

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your solution works a bit wrong.
That string in the question is exactly what it is. with the same number of "\". And I would like to remove all " " and "\" after "value", and your decision makes "host=HOME_SERVER 1526828015223382569"

Comment: @Ovenvan My solution works exactly as you asked: it removes all whitespace and backslashes after the word `value=`.

Comment: @Ovenvan, use this answer as follows: `filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "(\\G(?!^)|value=)([^\\\\\\s]*)[\\s\\\\]+", "$1$2"
    ]
  }
}` as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, hats off to another great answer..!! you learn something new everyday..Thank you!!

Comment: I get something like this" host=HOME_SERVER $1$2\"POST /platform/services/2.0/EnterpriseService HTTP/1.1\\\" 200 4075 \\\"-\\\" \\\"1C+Enterprise/8.3\\\" 0.141\" 1526829074124333436

Comment: @Ovenvan not sure if logStash gsub supports replacing captured groups. try `\1\2` instead of `$1$2`

Comment: unfortunately, the string does not change at all

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can this be implemented in ruby?

Comment: @Ovenvan Yes, it is the same regex and replacement pattern, just the syntax is a bit different, see [the Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/esuUNd).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works wonderfully. let me ask you one last question. how to change the syntax if you don't want to remove and replace with another character, for example, *

Comment: @Ovenvan If you need to replace then just add the replacement text after `$2`. E.g. to replace with `*`, [use 
 `\1\2*`](https://regex101.com/r/EKm0wB/3). Also, if you plan to replace all subsequent char occurrences, add `+` after `[\\\s]`, `[^\\\s]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot for your help, your solution works great